# Map this/self of source to specific field in target in Orika

Tags: java, orika

Let's have source classes

```
@Data
public class Source {
    private String name;
}

@Data
public class SourceParent {
    private String parentName;
}
```

and target classes

```
@Data
public class Target {
    private String name;
    private TargetParent parent;
}

@Data
public class TargetParent {
    private String parentName;
}
```

As you can see in Source I don't have the parent reference.

What I do is

```
Source s = findSource();
SourceParent sp = findParentForSource(s);
Target t = mapperFactory.map(s, Target.class);
mapperFactory.map(sp, t); //<--- Here is the problem
```

The problem is that I cannot map a `SourceParent` object to a specific field in `Target`.
I know how to do this using custom mappers or another "manual" ways. Is there a way to do it "Orika way"?

Something like:

```
 mapperFactory.classMap(SourceParent.class, Target.class)
    .fieldAtoB("?myslef?","parent")
    .register();
```

Comment: What about using a container class for your source objects and afterwards a single map call from the `SourceContainer` to the `TargetClass`?
`SourceContainer sc = new SourceContainer(s, sp); mapperFactory.map(sc, Target.class);`

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
mapperFactory.classMap(SourceParent.class, Target.class)
    .fieldAtoB("","parent")
    .register();
```